# MS Word VBA, Len() working on first table cell while not working on second one

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, find

I am trying to do some automated find and replace in some parts of the text. The first one works properly while the second one is returning an error, the issue is on the Len() function if I understand correctly.

```
Sub FindReplace()

Dim aTable As Table
Dim aCell, bCell As Cell

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each aTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
Set aCell = aTable.Cell(1, 2)
Set bCell = aTable.Cell(2, 2)


    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[Êïõôß 1]"
        .Replacement.Text = Trim(Left(aCell, Len(aCell) - 2))
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[Êïõôß 2]"
        .Replacement.Text = Trim(Left(bCell, Len(bCell) - 2))
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Next aTable

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Please for your help!

Comment: You should tell us what error you receive? What is the content of bCell?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ike.
The error is "Compile Error: Variable Required - can't assign to this expression"
The text on table's cell(1,2) is "George"
The text on table's cell(2,2) is "Athens"

Comment: And on which line do you get the error?

Comment: on ".Replacement.Text = Trim(Left(bCell, Len(bCell) - 2))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is within your variable declaration:

`Dim aCell, bCell As Cell`

`aCell` is dimmed implicitly as `Variant`.
Therefore `Len` can handle it by taking the default property of `Cell`

But `bCell` is dimmed as `Cell` which can't be passed to `Len`

Solution:
Be explicit in your dimming:

`Dim aCell As Cell, bCell As Cell`

And use `Len(aCell.Range.Text)` and `Len(bCell.Range.Text)` to retrieve the content of the cell.